# How to control where Outlook signature is created

Tags: vba, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, email-signature

I use code similar to the following VSTO C# to create an Outlook Signature:

```
var signature = WordApplication.EmailOptions.EmailSignature
signature.EmailSignatureEntries.Add("Signature Name", range);
```

Seeing as I have multiple email accounts, the signature is created in "Signatures on this device" - not in any of the email accounts.
Consequently, I can't manually set the "New messages" and "Replies/Forwards".

I don't want to programmatically set the "New messages" and "Replies/Forwards" values.
Can someone explain what is going on and how I can resolve my issue?

-- Edit --

I don't require roaming signatures (at this stage) and am happy for them to be stored in the Outlook Client. The problem is that I think Microsoft may have broken this functionality.

I have been using the above code (for years now), to manage email signatures. However, things have changed in Outlook sometime in the last 6 to 12 months.

My colleague and I see different "Signatures and Stationery" dialogs. Even though we are both on Office 365 v2302 Build 16.0.16130.20186 64bit.

His dialog allows the "New Messages" signature to be set. Mine does not.

The main difference I can see between our computers is that I am on Windows 11 whereas he is on Windows 10. We both have multiple email accounts configured within Outlook. I have a "Signatures on this device" option. He does not.

From my computer where the dialog DOESN'T work:

[image: My computer - dialog doesn't work]

From his computer where the dialog DOES work:

[image: From his computer where the dialog DOES work]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to [Christopher Edwards](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/93d43f8f-0957-4c49-8b88-db4fc5062c94)

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/unable-to-set-new-message-signature/66174399-4ab9-4c15-9c88-d0f1a7550a64?messageId=3a75ef23-35f6-4446-8a5a-52e7dc38223f

> I am actually using VBA and I have actually seen the same thing and I believe it is related to the Roaming Signatures feature that has now been rolled to 50% of Outlook 365 Desktops in the current build.
>
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=60371
>
> There is also a reg fix at the top of this thread - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/outlook/outlook-roaming-signature-vs-signatures-on-this-device/m-p/3672866
>
> More details here - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outlook-roaming-signatures-420c2995-1f57-4291-9004-8f6f97c54d15?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Answer (score 0):

Cloud signatures are not at all documented at his point. Outlook has an API for that (you can see the calls in Fiddler), but it has changed over the past few months, and I expect it to change further before Microsoft moves the API to Graph and documents it. All of this is just an educated guess...

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model (as well as Word object model) doesn't provide anything for roaming signatures (for keeping signatures in the mailbox, not client). You will not find anything for that when dealing with the Outlook object model.

Currently also Microsoft Graph API doesn't have support for signature settings. Email signatures are stored by the Outlook client, not within the mailbox. This is why users see different signatures across desktop, mobile, and web clients. The only settings like this available via Graph are settings stored at the mailbox level. These are accessed via `mailboxSettings` object: `automaticRepliesSetting`, `language`, `timeZone`, and `workingHours`. Refer to documentation [mailboxsettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailboxsettings), which lists all mailbox settings that can be managed through Graph.

There is Graph Feed Request submitted, you can upvote the request and provide you feedback, and Microsoft Product Engineering team can review and check the feasibility and consider for implementation.

[Make email signatures available on Graph](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/64dc82f2-2a17-ed11-a81b-6045bd7d68ae)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is using naming convention "Signature name (mail address).htm/rtf/txt" to your signature files show up under your account and be available in dropdowns "New messages" and "Replies/Forwards". Example:

Store files

- "MySignature (firstname.lastname@mycompany.com).htm"
- "MySignature (firstname.lastname@mycompany.com).rtf"
- "MySignature (firstname.lastname@mycompany.com).txt"

in signature folder "%appdata%\Microsoft\Signatures"

Outlook will automatically create folder "%appdata%\Microsoft\Signatures\MySignature (firstname.lastname@mycompany.com)_files".

Also that signature becomes available Outlook web client.
**Edit 7.2.2024**: Doesn't do that any longer for me.

This is undocumented, hence a hack. It worked with Outlook v2311 for me but may stop working in in future.